# How to make VB.Net List class more flexible for the caller

Tags: vb.net, list, class, generics, strong-typing

I am new to generics and collections in VB.Net. I've written my first class that creates a list of custom objects. While it seems to work, I believe I've done it in a crude sort of way and I would like to know how to improve it for the code that will need to invoke it. Here is the essential part of the list class:

```
Public Class Subscribers
    Public List As New List(Of Subscriber)
    Public Sub New()
        Dim sConnDatabase As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DatabaseConnString").ConnectionString
        Dim connection As New SqlConnection(sConnDatabase)
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand
        cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.Subscriber_v", connection)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        connection.Open()
        Dim objReader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            Do While objReader.Read()
            Dim id As Integer = objReader("SubscriberID")
            Dim s As Subscriber = New Subscriber(id)
            List.Add(s)
        Loop
        objReader.Close()
        connection.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Here is my first little test for using the class:

```
Dim n As String
Dim d As Integer

Dim allSubs As New Subscribers()
For Each Subscriber In allSubs.List
    n = Subscriber.SubscriberName
    d = Subscriber.DaysUntilExpired.ToString()
Next
```

A specific question regarding improvement would be: how to enable the caller to code something like:

```
For Each x In allSubs
n = x.SubscriberName
d = x.DaysUntilExpired.ToString()
Next
```

Would there be some way of coding the class such that the allSubs could be expressed without having to also specify .List - and some way of expressing it such that x would be recognized as being of type Subscriber.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make this work need to have `Subscribers` implement `IEnumerable(Of Subscribers)`.  The implementation can just forward to the `List` field

```
Public Class Subscribers Implements IEnumerable(Of Subscriber)
  Public Function GetEnumerator() As IEnumerator(Of Subscriber) _  
    Implements IEnumerable(Of Subscriber).GetEnumerator

    Return List.GetEnumerator()
  End Function

  Private Function GetEnumerator1() As IEnumerable _
    Implements IEnumerable.GetEnumerator

    Return List.GetEnumerator()
  End Function
End Class
```